# PowerShell проверка файла на FTP сервере

Tags: powershell

Всем добрый, подскажите пожалуйста как PowerShell'е подключиться к FTP серверу, проверить наличие файла например: test.txt и при его наличии просто удалить его. Буду максимально благодарен.

Comment: http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=416